# processing filelist produced by grep but names have spaces

Tags: grep, whitespace, backticks

I am trying to use the output of a grep command to make replacements in all files found. The problem is that some of the files found have spaces in their names. Here is a grep command simplified from the one I'm using (which finds multiple names at multiple mail hosts).

```
grep -Ril oldname@foo.com *
```

This produces a list that has the files I need, just listing the file names (the `-l` option). Using backticks I'm feeding the file names into a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pi -e 's/oldname\@foo\.com/newname\@bar.com/gi' `grep -Ril oldname@foo.com *`
```

This works when none of the files listed happen to have spaces in their names but when one does, it breaks.

With find I know I could use `-print0` and `xargs -0`, but there doesn't seem to be anything equivalent for `grep`.

I could put the output from `grep` into a file and then read that but now I want to know if this is somehow possible as a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

My grep has a -Z --null option to output NUL after every file name, you could use that with perl -0.

Comment: Somehow I didn't see that. I could have sworn I read the entire man page for grep. That technically solves my problem but I'm still doing something wrong. Adding Z as a switch to grep removes the new lines between files. But when I add -0 to my perl command, it's not recognizing the file separator correctly. It now complains that it cannot find (for instance) file1.txtfile2.txtfile3.txt which are the first three files in the directory.

Comment: Following up on my own comment, the answer it to use -Z with grep (as noted by jbowes) and then send that to perl using xargs -0 instead of perl -0. So: `grep -ZRilIE "foo" * | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/gi'`